# Angular 4.1.3 When using AOT, Service Factory returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

In my Angular app, I use a shared service that I need not to be a singleton as the data is updated constantly.

Service Factory:

```
import {DataService} from '../../../../shared/services/data.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

export const DataServiceProvider = {
    provide: DataService,
    useFactory(http: Http) {
        return new DataService(http);
    },
    deps: [Http]
};
```

When I run the app in JIT mode, the factory works fine, but when I build with the --aot flag, I receive the following error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

The service returned has a get() method which makes a call to the server.  I'm at a loss to understand what in AOT is breaking this seemingly simple functionality.

For additional reference, I inject the service in the constructor:

```
construct(
    dataService: DataService
) {
    super();
}
```

And call it in ngOnInit():

```
ngOnOnit() {
    this.subscribe(this.dataService.get(), (res) => { this.data = res });
}
```

I have some subscription functionality abstracted away from my component that handle unsubscribing to prevent memory leaks which is why that code may look so strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for AOT to work, all functions need to be statically analyzable. See [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5) for more information. Since you're exporting an object, and that object has an anonymous function on it, try exporting the function as well. Update your factory like this:

```
import {DataService} from '../../../../shared/services/data.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

export const DataServiceProvider = {
    provide: DataService,
    useFactory: dataServiceProviderUseFactory,
    deps: [Http]
};
export function dataServiceProviderUseFactory(http: Http) {
    return new DataService(http);
}
```

Comment: I thought with AOT that was supposed to fail on compile if it could not be analyzed.  I had changed the code from const factoryFunction = (http: Http) => return new DataService; because of the compile failures, but I would have never thought to export the function!  Thanks a ton.